# require('use-strict') doesn't work for me

Tags: node.js, node.js-stream, node.js-connect, node.js-client, node.js-domains

here, I am attempting to set value for read-only property but I am not getting any error:

HERE IS MY CODE:

```
require('use-strict');

function Employee(firstname) {
    var _firstname = firstname;

    Object.defineProperty(this, 'firstName', {
        get: function () { return _firstname },
        //set: function (value) { _firstname = value }
    });
}

var employee = new Employee('Fawad');

employee.firstName = 'Yasir'; //Attempting to set a value for read-only property.

console.log(employee.firstName);
```

Comment: I don't think you need the `use-strict` package as you should be able to just use `node --use_strict` to force strict mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation for the [use-strict](https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-strict) package:

> The implementation works by patching Node's internal module.wrapper
>   array, and then freezing it, so that further modifications are not
>   possible.
>
> Also, this means that ***the current module will not be affected***. ***You
>   should still "use strict" in the module that does
>   require('use-strict').*** This module applies strictness to all future
>   modules loaded by your program.

Comment: Why would you use a module instead of the default `use script` mode? LE: I got it, it's for auto-enabling strict mode on all loaded modules.

Answer (score 0):

Use of "use strict"; at the top of page worked for me although this approach is usually used for JavaScript development. I was trying to use one of the node.js packages which didn't worked.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this, but FYI `node.js` ***is*** Javascript . The module you are using just prepends `'use strict';` to every other module that is required afterward.

Comment: but anyhow, 'use strict' fulfilled my needs.

Comment: Yes, as I quoted in my answer. `'use strict';` is needed to make the current script run in strict mode. `require('use-strict');` only makes other modules run in strict mode, but doesn't affect the current one.